# Implicit conversion function to trait with a single method

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

```
Scala 2.11.4
```

I have the following trait

```
trait MyTrait{
   def met(msg: String): Unit
}
```

and class

```
class MyClass{

   def ac(mt: MyTrait) = {
      //do some job
   }
}
```

Now, I want to invoke `ac` as follows:

```
val myClass = new MyClass
myClass.as((msg: String) => println(msg)) //meaning that just print out Strings to stdout
```

So, I tried to add implicit conversion to `MyTrait`:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def met(msgString: String): Unit
  implicit def function2MyTrait(f: String => Unit): MyTrait = new MyTraitImpl(f)

  private[this] class MyTraitImpl(f: String => Unit) extends MyTrait{
    override def met(msgString: String): Unit = f(msgString)
  }
}
```

but it refuses to compile:

```
Error:(16, 89) type mismatch;
 found   : String => Unit
 required: com.test.trace.MyTrait
```

I came from Java 8. Is there a way to do such a thing in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `function2MyTrait` needs to live in the companion object:

   ```
   trait MyTrait {
     def met(msgString: String): Unit
   }
   object MyTrait {
     implicit def function2MyTrait(f: String => Unit): MyTrait = new MyTraitImpl(f)

     private[this] class MyTraitImpl(f: String => Unit) extends MyTrait{
       override def met(msgString: String): Unit = f(msgString)
     }
   }
   ```
2. This will be no longer be necessary in Scala 2.12, as it'll allow using lambdas to implement `MyTrait` without going through `String => Unit`.

Comment: Actually, just tried it and it now compiles fine. But I have not come across with companion objects for `trait`s before. How come is it common? Is it somewhat similar to what we have in Java 8 (static methods in interfaces)?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to static methods in interfaces. The difference from Java 8 is that this existed from beginning (or at least for a very very long time), so it's more widely used. In respect to companion objects, there is no difference between classes and traits.

Comment: How come this does not work: `implicit def function2MyTrait(f: String => Unit): MyTrait = new MyTrait{def met = f}`  The way I read it is that an anonymous class extending MyTrait is created in which the method met is implemented. But the compiler compains about met not being implemented.

Comment: @Samar It doesn't work because your method has the wrong signature to _implement_ `met`, it just _overloads_ it instead. It should be `def met(s: String) = f(s)`.